# chpasswd encrypted option failing in Ubuntu Core 20

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, encryption, ubuntu-core

I have an Ubuntu Core 20 VM.  using the below script file adding a user and trying to change password with below lines of code.

script file is executed with root access

`File.sh`:

```
user="test"
user_password="encryptedpassword"

adduser --extrausers $user --gecos "First Last,RoomNumber,WorkPhone,HomePhone" --disabled-login
echo $user:$user_password | chpasswd -e
```

and getting below error

```
chpasswd: cannot lock /etc/passwd; try again later.
```

How do I set an encrypted password for a new user created in Ubuntu Core?